# grep --color=auto with -i option disables the matching text color, why?

Tags: windows-vista, cygwin, grep, zsh

I was messing around with `grep` and put this in my .zshenv:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=auto"
export GREP_COLORS='mt=1;34'
```

I was bonking my head on the keyboard and changing `GREP_COLORS` around for a minute trying to figure out why the folder colors were working, but the matching text wasn't.

I was doing this:

```
$ grep -R -n -i -e "functionFoo\(" --include=*.cs --exclude-dir=Logs *
```

The line number and file names were set with the default colors, but the matching text wasn't.

After spending [way too much time](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html), I thought to do this:

```
$ grep -R -n -e "functionFoo\(" --include=*.cs --exclude-dir=Logs *
```

(I removed the `-i` option.)  That's all it took to get the matching text to correctly show up in bold blue.  This is a Cygwin on Vista setup, with rxvt running zsh.

**Any idea why grep colors would break on specifying a case-insensitive match?**

**Update:** Under cygwin 1.7, it's a little bit better - case insensitive search works correctly, but it only highlights the word that matches the expression exactly.  In other words, "FunctionFoo" highlights "FunctionFoo" but not "functionFoo" and vice versa.  Probably a grep issue so I'll be submitting it to that list.

Comment: This works for me using GNU grep 2.5.4

Comment: works for me, GNU grep 2.5.3, under `bash` on debian lenny and on cygwin. what version grep? what system?

Comment: GNU grep 2.5.3, and `CYGWIN_NT-6.0-WOW64 AAF 1.5.25(0.156/4/2) 2008-06-12 19:34 i686 Cygwin` is the `uname -a` output.

Comment: i've got the same buildtime on my cygwin but it's CYGWIN_NT-5.1 (on winXP here). my best guess is you're hitting some bug in cygwin .. likely some difference in XP-cmd.exe vs Vista-cmd.exe that hasn't been addressed properly in cygwin's terminfo/termcap. you should probably drop a bugreport to cygwin about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Cygwin but to grep. You need to set the locale environment variables in your shell, like LANG.

Taken from the grep(1) manual:

> The  locale  for  category  LC_foo  is
>   specified  by  examining the three
>   environment variables LC_ALL, LC_foo,
>   LANG, in that order.  The first of
>   these variables that is set specifies
>   the locale.  For example, if LC_ALL is
>   not set, but LC_MESSAGES is set to
>   pt_BR, then the Brazilian Portuguese
>   locale  is used  for  the  LC_MESSAGES
>   category.  The C locale is used if
>   none of these environment variables
>   are set, if the locale catalog is not
>   installed, or if grep was not compiled
>   with national language support (NLS).

Try for example:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 grep -R -n -i -e "functionFoo\(" --include=*.cs --exclude-dir=Logs *
```

That should fix your problem, and works for me with GNU grep 2.5.4 and bash 3.2.48(1)-release.

Comment: Almost works.  When I set the shell variable inline like that, it works if `LANG` is currently set to `C.UTF-8` (default).  When I edited my `.zprofile` to include the line `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, then it ceases to work (even setting `LANG` inline).

Comment: What version of zsh are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem using Msys MinGW. I didn't find a way to resolve it so ended up using:

```
ack -i PATTERN
```

which does colors and case insensitivity correctly.